# Alternative solution to $\cos\frac{2\pi}{17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When I saw Gauss's original solution to $17$ sided gon, his method seemed all clever and tricky. I am wondering if there are some other ways to evaluate $$\cos\frac{2\pi}{17}$$

Comment: Could you link Gauss' original solution?

Comment: @iHubble I read it in my book **Higher Algebra by Jm Barnard and Child** and I couldn't find his solution on internet.

Comment: Are you familiar with Galois Theory?

Comment: No I haven't started it yet..

Comment: [This](http://home.scarlet.be/j-willekens/store/p17.pdf) paper explains how to derive an expression for $\cos(2\pi/17)$ using Galois Theory. That's really the only other way I know unfortunately...

Comment: [$$
\cos\frac{2\pi}{17}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}+2\sqrt{17+3\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}-2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}}{16}.
$$](http://www.nn.iij4u.or.jp/~hsat/misc/math/drawing/heptadecagon.html)

Comment: See my manuscript [*A Detailed and Elementary Solution to* $x^{17} = 1$](http://pballew.net/Constructable_17gon.pdf), especially Chapters 3 and 4.