# Logic behind a Geometric Construction of regular heptadecagon

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, geometric-construction

I'm reading a Chinese book "Methods of Mathematical Physics" by Wu Chongshi.

During introduction of complex analysis, it explains a Geometric Construction of regular heptadecagon.

Task: to achieve $a=2\sin(\pi/17)$

1. Let $x = e^{i2\pi / 17}$, so $x^0, x^1, \cdots, x^{16}$ are all the
   roots for equation $x^{17}=1$.
2. Let $s = x^1 + x^9 + x^{9^2} + x^{9^3} + \cdots + x^{9^7}$ and $s'= x^3 + x^{3^3} + x^{3^5} + \cdots + x^{3^{15}}$.

   So $s = x^1 + x^9 + x^{13} + x^{15} + x^{16} + x^8 + x^4 + x^2$,
   $s'= x^3 + x^{10} + x^5 + x^{11} + x^{14} + x^7 + x^{12} + x^6$.

   Since $s+s'=-1$ , $ss'=-4$, one has $s=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{17}-1)$,
   $s'=-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{17}+1)$.
3. Let $s=p+p'$, $s'=q+q'$, where $p = x^1 + x^{13} + x^{16} + x^4$, $p'= x^9 + x^{15} + x^8 + x^2$,$q = x^3 + x^5 + x^{14} + x^{12}$, $q'= x^{10} + x^{11} + x^7 + x^6$.

   Since $pp'=-1$, $qq'=-1$, one has
   $p=\frac{1}{2}(s+\sqrt{s^2+4})$, $q=\frac{1}{2}(s'+\sqrt{s'^2+4})$.
4. Again, let $r=x^1+x^{16}$, $r'=x^{13}+x^4$, one has
   $r+r'=p$, $rr'=q$, hence $r=\frac{1}{2}(p+\sqrt{p^2-4q})$.
5. Finally, $a=\sqrt{2-r}$.

Now, with all these steps quite good and smart, my question is, why at the beginning of step 2, $s$ and $s'$ are construct as $$s = x^1 + x^9 + x^{9^2} + x^{9^3} + \cdots + x^{9^7}$$ and $$s'= x^3 + x^{3^3} + x^{3^5} + \cdots + x^{3^{15}}$$?

These are interesting exponential forms, is there anything special behind the form? some reason, logic?

-- update

maybe i explain a little bit more.

From Fermat's small theorem, that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1(\text{mod } p)$ , it's obvious that 
$$3^{17-1}\equiv 1 (\text{mod } 17)$$
hence $$9^8=(3^2)^8=3^{16}=3^{17-1}\equiv 1 (\text{mod } 17)$$
that's why we could let $$s=\Sigma_i x^{a_i}$$ where $$a_{i+1}=a_i^9$$
similiarly, $$s'=\Sigma_i x^{3a_i}$$

But, when the guy first came out of the idea, how "dare" he do so?
How could he be sure that

1. there will have $s+s'=-1$ and $ss'=-4$ so that $s$ and $s'$ are
   solvable?
2. $s$ and $s'$ could be further broken down to $s=p+p'$, $s'=q+q'$ as above?

Is the guy simply found this idea by luck?
Or, there's some math supporting his idea, just like the Fermat's little theorem supports compose $s$ by 8 components? I suspect there's some groundings from number theory...

Comment: interesting... i'll try, but I doubt I can do it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516142/how-does-cos2-pi-257-look-like-in-real-radicals/516233#516233 reference link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$
Write $\omega = e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{17}}$.

I have only the time to write down the beginning of the argument. Very briefly, the idea is that the extension $\Q(\omega)/\Q$ has degree 16, and can be built via extensions of degree $2$.

Its Galois group $G$ is abelian, isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\Z_{17}^{\star}$, via $\omega \mapsto \omega^{k}$, where $k \in \Z_{17}^{\star}$.

Now $\Z_{17}^{\star}$ is generated by $3$, so $G$ is generated by $\sigma : \omega \mapsto \omega^{3}$. ) So $\Span {\sigma^{2}}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index two, and corresponds to a field $F$, with $\Q \subseteq F \subseteq \Q(\omega)$ with $\lvert F : \Q \rvert = 2$. This field $F$ contains
$$
s = \sum_{\tau \in \Span {\sigma^{2}}} \tau(\omega)
$$
(just check that this is left invariant by $\sigma^{2}$, and also note that $\sigma^{2} : \omega \mapsto \omega^{9}$), and then $F$ also contains $\sigma(s) = s'$, as every intermediate field is Galois.

Also note that obviously $\sigma^{2}(s) = s$.
Therefore
$$
\sigma(s + s') = \sigma(s) + \sigma(\sigma(s)) = \sigma(s) + s = s'+ s,
$$
and similarly $\sigma(s s') = s s'$. It follows that $s + s, s s'\in \Q$, and therefore $F$ can be obtained from $\Q$ by adding the roots of the rational polynomial
$$
x^{2} - (s + s') x + s s´.
$$

Comment: Gosh. I'm totally lost. Nevertheless, it's glad to see that behind the solution there's not pure luck or "talent" or "instinct", but a system, which is more attainable. I guess the area to pick up is algebra and I've heard that Michael Artin's book is a good introduction. But math is such a big world. Would you please recommend a book that I could self-study and understand the whole solution and your explanation of the idea?

Comment: @athos, thanks. And I have omitted things like the trace map! What you could do is look up some Galois Theory. Artin's book is excellent. I believe the calculations are done in full, as an application of the theory, also in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I.

Comment: not in Artin's book as far as I can see. What reference do you use ?