# a conjectured continued fraction for $\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2n}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, gamma-function, continued-fractions, conjectures

Given a [complex number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) $\begin{aligned}\frac{z}{n}=x+iy\end{aligned}$ and a [gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma(z)$ with $x\gt0$, it is conjectured that the following [continued fraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for [$\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2n}\right)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent) is true

$$\begin{split}\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2n}\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{z+n}{4z+2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3z+n}{4z+2n}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{4z+2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3z+2n}{4z+2n}\right)}\\&=\cfrac{2z}{2z+n+\cfrac{(n)(4z+n)} {3(2z+n)+\cfrac{(2z+2n)(6z+2n)}{5(2z+n)+\cfrac{(4z+3n)(8z+3n)}{7(2z+n)+\ddots}}}}\end{split}$$

***Corollaries***:

By taking the limit(which follows after [abel's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)) 
$$
\begin{aligned}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2}\right)}{2z}=\frac{\pi}{4}\end{aligned},
$$ 
we recover the well known [continued fraction for $\pi$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)

$$\begin{aligned}\cfrac{4}{1+\cfrac{1^2}{3+\cfrac{2^2}{5+\cfrac{3^2}{7+\ddots}}}}=\pi\end{aligned}$$

If we let $z=1$ and $n=2$,then we have [the square root of $2$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2) $$\begin{aligned}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1} {2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}}=\sqrt{2}\end{aligned}$$

***Q***: How do we prove rigorously that the conjectured continued fraction is true and converges for all complex numbers $z$ with $x\gt0$?

***Update***:I initially defined the continued fraction $\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2}\right)$ for only natural numbers,but as a matter of fact it holds for all complex numbers $z$ with real part greater than zero.Moreover,this continued fraction is a special case of the general continued fraction found in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739431/conjectured-general-continued-fraction-for-the-quotient-of-gamma-functions).

Comment: That is impressive. How did you come up with it?

Comment: Really, how did you get this? If you provide some of the methods you used, there is a better chance someone would be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Nicco, thank you for the link. Sorry, but I don't have anything to contribute so far

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proposed continued fraction
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2n}\right)=\cfrac{2z}{2z+n+\cfrac{(n)(4z+n)} {3(2z+n)+\cfrac{(2z+2n)(6z+2n)}{5(2z+n)+\cfrac{(4z+3n)(8z+3n)}{7(2z+n)+\ddots}}}}
\end{equation} 
can be written as
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{z\pi}{4z+2n}\right)=\cfrac{2z/\left( 2z+n \right)}{1+\cfrac{(n)/\left( 2z+n \right)\cdot(4z+n)/\left( 2z+n \right)} {3+\cfrac{(2z+2n)/\left( 2z+n \right)\cdot(6z+2n)/\left( 2z+n \right)}{5+\cfrac{(4z+3n)/\left( 2z+n \right)\cdot(8z+3n)/\left( 2z+n \right)}{7+\ddots}}}}
\end{equation} 
Denoting $u=\cfrac{z}{4z+2n}$, the factors of the numerators are
\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{2z+n}=1-4u\,;\quad\frac{4z+n}{2z+n}=1+4u\,;\quad\frac{2z+2n}{2z+n}=2-4u\,;\quad\frac{6z+2n}{2z+n}=2+4u\,;\cdots
\end{equation} 
Then, the fraction can be simplified as
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\tan\left(\pi u\right)=\cfrac{4u}{1+\cfrac{\cfrac{1-16u^2}{1\cdot3}} {1+\cfrac{\cfrac{4-16u^2}{3\cdot5}}{1+\cfrac{\cfrac{9-16u^2}{5\cdot7}}{1+\ddots}}}}
\end{equation} 
It is thus a special case of the continued fraction found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1798142/348034):
\begin{equation}
\tan\left(\alpha\tan^{-1}z\right)=\cfrac{\alpha z}{1+\cfrac{\frac{(1^2-\alpha^2)z^2}{1\cdot 3}} {1+\cfrac{\frac{(2^2-\alpha^2)z^2}{3\cdot 5}}{1+\cfrac{\frac{(3^2-\alpha^2)z^2}{5\cdot 7}}{1+\ddots}}}}
\end{equation} 
here $z=1$ and $\alpha=4u$. The brilliant proof is based on a continued fraction due to Nörlund.

Answer (score 5):

The ratio
$$\tan\dfrac{\pi z}{4z+2n} 
= \dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{z+n}{4z+2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{3z+n}{4z+2n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{z}{4z+2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{3z+2n}{4z+2n}\right)}\hspace{100mu}\tag1$$
can be obtained, applying "real" identity

> $$\sin\pi x = \dfrac\pi{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)}\hspace{100mu}\tag2$$

to the expression
$$\tan\dfrac\pi2\dfrac z{2z+n} 
= \dfrac{\sin\pi\dfrac z{4z+2n}}{\sin\pi\dfrac{z+n}{4z+2n}},$$
so it looks nice and quite correct.

Continued fraction can be obtained, using [known continued fraction of the tangent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued%20fraction%20tan%20x) function in the form of
$$\tan \dfrac{\pi x}4 = \cfrac x{1+\operatorname{
\Large K}\hspace{-27mu}\phantom{\Big|}_{k=1}^{\large ^{\,\infty}}\cfrac{(2k-1)^2-x^2}2}\hspace{100mu}\tag3$$
with 
$$x=\dfrac{2z}{2z+n}.$$