Closed form of $\sin{\frac{\pi}{257}}$ and $\sin{\frac{\pi}{65537}}$
Bit of a soft question. I am quite eager to find a closed form (expression involving nested roots and integers) for the value $\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{65537}\right)}$ since $65537$ is a Fermat prime and thus there must be a closed form. I tried using Wolframalpha but it didn't provide an adequate answer. I don't know of any other calculators that could give me my desired result. So, does anyone have images or links to these sought-after closed forms?
Edit: I forgot that $257$ is also a Fermat prime number, so I'd like a closed form for $\sin{\frac{\pi}{257}}$ as well, thank you.

Do you speak German? This old paper https://www.digizeitschriften.de/id/252457811_1894%7Clog34?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B195%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D gives something to do with a construction on page 195 (179 in the journal) for 65537

@QC_QAOA I'll see if I can decipher that, in the meanwhile just wanted to let you know I edited my question.

I think you can use the answer here to get $\sin(\pi/257)$ : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516142/how-does-cos2-pi-257-look-like-in-real-radicals

I'll add this link https://web.archive.org/web/20170105062949/http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?messageID=1382422&tstart=0 to an old Conway post for $65537$. I can't get the link to work but its possible you might

I took the liberty of removing the "algebraic groups" tag, which would have been extremely misleading, and added "nested radicals", which I think is more to the point for your goals. :)

By the way, we should be aware that, although nested-radical expressions for Fermat-prime-order roots of unity (and corresponding sines and cosines) exist, involving only square roots... any root of unity has a nested-radical expression, because the Galois group is abelian (so, solvable). Further, there is a computationally effective (though eventually burdensome) algorithm to obtain it. In particular, then, the nested-radical expression is not special to Fermat-prime-order...

$\sqrt{\text{Do you really want to go there?}}$, maybe?

I disagree that this is a soft question.  A given expression either is or isn't a closed form, and either is or isn't accompanied by a proof.

@paulgarrett But, a nested real radical expression (all radicands positive) exists for a primitive $n$th root of unity $\zeta$ iff $\zeta$ is a constructible complex number (so when $n$ is a product of a power of $2$ and distinct Fermat primes). That is, in all other cases, we run into casus irreducibilis. Since OP specifically wants to avoid complex numbers, there is something special about Fermat-prime order.

@Jacob, I'm confused by your comment: those roots of unity themselves cannot be real numbers, so how could we reach them by square roots of positive reals? Can you clarify, please?

@paulgarrett Ahh, I mean with respect to their real and imaginary parts. A constructible complex number is one whose real and imaginary parts are constructible real numbers, and a complex number having a nested real radical expression is defined likewise. The fact that these two coincide for the roots of unity is shown in section 3 of this handout from Brian Conrad.

As far as I see, the comments should provide the required references.
Case of $\sin\frac{\pi}{257}$.
HackR provided a link to the question by Tito Piezas III on a representation of $\cos\frac{2\pi}{257}$ as a tower of nested real radicals. In his answer is provided a formula for $w_4=4\cos\frac{256\pi}{257}$. Then $$\sin\frac{\pi}{257}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{w_4}4\right)^2}.$$
Case of $\sin\frac{\pi}{65537}$.
QC_QAOA provided
a link to an old Conway's post about the construction of the $65537$-gon. The construction is very cumbersome, but there is provided the sketch of it. But since I saw deleted link-only answers, and, moreover, QC_QAOA failed to get the link to work, I copied the relevant text below and formatted the formulae.

From: Antreas P. Hatzipolakis
Posted: Feb 8, 1999 5:25 PM
... I recall that a Conway's student tried once to construct the r. $65537$-gon using a computer.
I located Conway's posting, so let him tell us the story:

Subject: Re: 17 sides
From: John Conway conway@math.Princeton.EDU
Date: Tue, 4 Nov 1997 12:26:51 -0500 (EST)
To: geometry-research@forum.swarthmore.edu
On Tue, 28 Oct 1997, Bradley Brock wrote:


How could Gauss find the length of the $17$-side polygon side???

On a related note:
I remember that one of my friends in grad school
showed John Conway the output from a little
Mathematica program that gave the sides of
the $257$-gon.
Brad

Forgive me for not replying to this before now. It obviously
refers to John Steinke, who was a graduate student here some time
ago, and is a bit misleading. What happened was that I proposed
to him the problem of finding a publishable construction for the
$65537$-gon, and suggested various methods, and he did the $257$-gon
as a baby-example.
You are probably aware of the fact that Hermes worked for
many years on finding a construction for the $65537$-gon. I don't
really believe the legend, that this was because his teacher
told him to "go away and don't bother me again until you've
found how to construct a regular $65537$-gon!", but many years
ago I did see in Gottingen a cardboard box that was said to
contain Hermes's work on the problem.
However, I can hardly believe that he really got anywhere,
because the size of the problem is much bigger than one might suppose.
I did work out, though, a way of phrasing the solution that could
probably fit into $20$ closely-written pages, and could definitely be
found nowadays by computer. However, I think Steinke lost interest
in the problem and I never tried to persuade anyone else to do it.
It's obvious from the start that there's a "solution" in the form
of a set of 16 quadratic equations, the coefficients of each being
functions of the roots of the previous ones. The trouble is that
those functions get pretty complicated, and it would take a very
large book to write them all down in that form. Let for instance
$a,A$ ; $b,B$; $c,C$ be the roots of the first three. Then the general
element of the field they generate is a linear combination with
rational coefficients of the $8$ numbers
$$abc, abC, aBc, aBC, Abc, AbC, ABc, ABC$$
and so to specify the (two) coefficients of the next equation
is to give a list of $16$ rational numbers (which we can actually
make be integers). In a similar way, to specify the coefficients of
the $14$th equation we'll need $2^{14} = 16384$ integers.
My proposed form of the solution involves going about half-way,
to about the $8$th equation, in this manner, thereby setting up names
for all elements of the subfield of degree $256$. Then one works
from the other end, working out the quadratic satisfied by a
particular $65537$th root of unity over the next field down, and so on.
Let's call it Z - then this equation is $t^2 - (Z + Z^{-1})t + 1 = 0$,
and so we invent a name, $Y$, for $Z + Z^{-1}$. In the same way, we
invent names for the coefficients of the quadratic defining Y,
and so on. By the time we get half-way, we'll've define $Z, Z^{-1}, Y, \dots$
in terms of about $512$ numbers in the degree $256$ subfield. So the
solution reduces to writing out the length $256$ names of each of
these $512$ numbers.
I would very much like to see this calculation done, since
there might well be some patterns that would enable one to write
down the answer more simply than the way sketched above.
John Conway

Additionally, let me quote the first sentence of the last paragraph
of Duane W. DeTemple's paper [1, p. 107]:


Remarks on the Construction of the Regular $65537$-gon. We have already
observed that $g = 3$ is a primitive root of $p = 65537$. The sum, product, and
relative order of period pairs must then be computed (one feels sorry for the
computerless Hermes!).



Duane W. DeTemple: Carlyle Circles and the Lemoine Simplicity.
The Americn Mathematical Monthly 98(1991) 97 - 108.

Note: DDeT refers to several regular heptakaidecagon constructions,
but not to that one (Lebesgue's) I posted earlier.
Antreas

Partial Answer
Recall DeMoivre's Formula:
$$(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))^n = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)$$
Let $\theta = \frac{\pi}{n}$.  Then:
$$(\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}))^n = -1$$
Let $x = \sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$.  If $n \ge 2$, then $\cos$ and $\sin$ are both nonnegative, so:
$$\boxed{(\sqrt{1-x^2} + ix)^n = -1}$$
By the Binomial Theorem:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}(ix)^{n-k} = -1$$
Or, breaking it down into separate summations based on the value of $k \bmod 4$,
$$\sum_{k \equiv 0} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}x^{n-k} - i\sqrt{1-x^2}\sum_{k \equiv 1} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{(k-1)/2}x^{n-k} - \sum_{k \equiv 2} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}x^{n-k} + i\sqrt{1-x^2}\sum_{k \equiv 3} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{(k-1)/2}x^{n-k} = -i^{-n}$$
Move the odd square roots to one side of the equation:
$$i\sqrt{1-x^2} \left(
\sum_{k \equiv 3} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{(k-1)/2}x^{n-k}
- \sum_{k \equiv 1} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{(k-1)/2}x^{n-k}
\right)
 = -i^{-n} - \sum_{k \equiv 0} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}x^{n-k} + \sum_{k \equiv 2} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}x^{n-k}$$
And now we can just square it, producing a polynomial equation:
$$(x^2 - 1) \left(
\sum_{k \equiv 3} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{(k-1)/2}x^{n-k}
- \sum_{k \equiv 1} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{(k-1)/2}x^{n-k}
\right)^2
 = \left(-i^{-n} - \sum_{k \equiv 0} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}x^{n-k} + \sum_{k \equiv 2} {n \choose k} (1-x^2)^{k/2}x^{n-k}\right)^2$$
For example, for $n=3$, each summation contains only one item, and we get:
$$(x^2 - 1) \left({3 \choose 3} (1-x^2)^{1}x^{0}- {3 \choose 1} (1-x^2)^{0}x^{2}\right)^2 = \left(-i^{-3} - {3 \choose 0} (1-x^2)^{0}x^{3} + {3 \choose 2} (1-x^2)^{1}x^{1}\right)^2$$
$$(x^2 - 1) ((1-x^2) - 3x^{2})^2 = (-i - x^{3} + 3(1-x^2)x)^2$$
$$(x^2 - 1)(1 - 4x^2)^2 = (-i + 3x - 4x^3)^2$$
$$x^2 - 8x^4 + 16x^6 - 1 + 8x^2 - 16x^4 = -1 - 3ix + 4ix^3 - 3ix + 9x^2 - 12x^4 + 4ix^3 - 12x^4 + 16x^6$$
$$8ix^3 - 6ix = 0$$
$$2ix(4x^2 - 3) = 0$$
$$x\in \{0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\}$$
But since $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is in Quadrant 1, its sine must be positive, and so $x = \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
Expanding and solving the polynomials for $n=257$ and $n=65537$ is left as an exercise for the reader 

Somewhat speculative answer since actually carrying out this procedure would be a ton of work.
If you represent $t = \frac{1}{2^w + 1}$ in binary you get a repeating decimal, explicitly with the formula:
$$t = \frac{1}{2^w + 1} = t\cdot 2^{2w} - (2^w - 1)$$
so you want
$$s = \sin(\pi\cdot t) = \sin(\pi\cdot t \cdot 2^{2w} - \pi\cdot(2^w - 1))$$
then if you repeatedly apply the transforms
$$\sin(a - b) = \sin a \cdot \cos b - \cos a \cdot \sin b$$
$$\cos(a - b) = \cos a \cdot \cos b + \sin a \cdot \sin b$$
$$\sin(2^k \cdot x) = 2^k \cdot \sin(x) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\cos(2^j \cdot x)$$
$$\cos(2^k \cdot x) = T_{2^k}(\cos(x))$$
$$\sin(\pi) = -1$$
$$\cos(\pi) = 0$$
where $T$ is Chebychev polynomials of the first kind, greatly simplified by $\cos(\pi) = 0$, and labelling $c = \cos(\pi \cdot t)$, you should be able (speculatively, I haven't actually done this) to get some formula of the form:
$$s = g_s(s, c)$$
$$c = g_c(s, c)$$
where $g$s are some elementary function.  Then solve for $s$.  Or maybe $g$ will end up being some fairly large polynomial with difficult to find roots.
